# What´s the explenation for this in this piece of code, (related to strings in C)?

Tags: c

Im new to coding and C, and cant found an explenation to this can someone explain me please:
[Piece of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bbmo.png)
Why does those two last random characters pop up if I enter 8, but if I input 6 it doesn´t.
It is related to null characters or something? Please I need an explenation.

I tried almost everything, still figuring out, can´t found an explenation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post pictures of text. Instead copy&paste it directly into the question as formatted text.

Comment: You don't initialize your variables.

Comment: If your compiler did not print a warning about using a variable without assigning a value first, you should increase warning level. For gcc or clang use `-Wextra -Wall -pedantic`. If it did show a warning, you should not ignore it.

Comment: In C, strings are actually nul-terminated character sequences. `printf` expects to get a string. Where do you ensure that you provide nul termination? (And that 0 byte also needs some room in your array...)

Comment: You don't terminate your string. Strings have to end with `0` in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, strings need to end with a special character called the [`NUL` termination character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). The value of that character is `0`.

If you pass a string to printf (`%s`), it expects the string to end with `0`.

Since you don't set the `NUL` termination, the `printf` function does not know when to stop reading characters from the string.

This is called a [buffer over read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_over-read): you're reading past your allocated buffer (`aster` in that case).

Make sure to terminate `aster` and it'll work.

One way of achieving this would be to change `char aster[n];` to `char aster[n+1];` (allocate one character more for the `NUL` termination character) and then setting `aster[n] = 0;`.

Consider `n = 3` memory will look like this: (OUT OF BOUNDS means the memory afterwards doesn't belong to `aster` and is something else, we don't know what it is).

```
aster[0] = ?
aster[1] = ?
aster[2] = ?
aster[3] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[4] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[5] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[6] = ... and so on
```

After your code memory will look like this:

```
aster[0] = *
aster[1] = *
aster[2] = *
aster[3] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[4] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[5] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[6] = ... and so on
```

printf will look at each character. It should stop at `aster[3]` but it doesn't know that because there isn't a well-defined character at that place. This is why it might work sometimes, but other times it will not work. It's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Changing the code to always set the `NUL` character it will look like this:

```
aster[0] = *
aster[1] = *
aster[2] = 0
aster[3] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[4] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[5] = ? <OUT OF BOUNDS>
aster[6] = ... and so on
```

In that case `printf` will NEVER read past `aster[2]`.

In any case, it's *always* a no-no to read or write past your memory buffers ;)

Also you need to intialize your loop variable `i` to `0`.

Comment: Oh okay now I understand why it is impossible for it to work, thank you so much!!

Comment: @gaezvr No problem! I'll be happy if you could upvote and mark my answer as "accepted" - thanks.

Comment: it says I need reputation, i cant upvote, however i marked it as accepted